# What will happen to God when the universe ends?

Tags: gods, universe

Unlike humans who are mortal, what will happen to God/The creator when everything in the universe ends someday and there's no more life?
It's fascinating how they live forever

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Also, do clarify your doubt properly in that exactly what you want in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cycle of creation and destruction continues. God will create a new universe.

> RV.10.190.3. Dhātar, the great Creator, then formed **in due order Sun** and Moon.
> He formed in order Heaven and Earth, the regions of the air, and light.

> BG 9.7 — O son of Kunti, all elementary world becomes "My" nature at end of cycle(Kalpa); Again "I" create them at the beginning of the cycle.

> BG 8.18 - On arrival of day, all manifestations originate from "Unmanifest"; On arrival of night they annihilate into [what is] known as "Unmanifest" only.

> BG 8.19 - This [same] elementary world only happens again & again; Annihilates upon arrival of night, [and] originates upon arrival of day.

Comment: I remember reading another piece of Vedic knowledge on this topic, but forget where and I cannot find it. But it said that basically every instance of the universe is contained within each breath of Lord Vishnu. So when he starts inhaling, a new universe is created and expands, and then when he starts exhaling -- it starts contracting until it is back to nothingness. And the cycle repeats with each breath. 

This also kind of coincides with our current understanding of astrophysics as well (not the cycles but universe expansion/contraction).

Comment: This maybe found in the Srimada Bhagvatam [ŚB 10.87.41](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/87/41/) & [Brahma-saṁhitā 5.48](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bs/5/48/) @Ruslan  ...  :)